# "Bad value" error when using UrlFetchApp.fetch() method

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have seen different versions of this question asked, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the answers. I have the following code running once an hour to send information from emails to my Wix site to parse the information. Once the function gets a return from my Wix site, I want to trigger another function to notify subscribers:

```
var POST_URL = "https://www.myWixSite.com/_functions/shiurAddition";
var EMAIL_URL = "https://www.myWixSite.com/_functions/shiurNotify";

function gmailInboxToWix() {
  var oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("toBeProcessed");
  var newLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("ProcessedByScript");
  var threads = oldLabel.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var HTML = messages[j].getBody()
      var Date = messages[j].getDate()
      messages[j].markRead()
      var data = {Date: Date, HTML: HTML};
      var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "payload": data
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options)
      Logger.log(response)
      var emailResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(EMAIL_URL, response);
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(oldLabel).refresh();
    threads[i].addLabel(newLabel);
  }
}
```

When running this, I am getting an error from Google:

> Exception: Bad value (line 24, file "Code"

Line 24 is this code:

```
 var emailResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(EMAIL_URL, JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about `response`, I think that `JSON.stringify(response)` of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(EMAIL_URL, JSON.stringify(response))` is not correct argument. The 2nd argument of `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is the object. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) Could you please confirm `response` again.

Comment: The syntax should be `var emailResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(EMAIL_URL, options)`, just like you did with `var response `. The only difference is that you should ajust the new options to the new payload.

Comment: @Tanaike Trying it without the JSON.stringify returns the same issue. I adjusted the code above to reflect this

Comment: Thank you for replying. You are using `options` at `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options)`. I think that this is the correct object. But I didn't think that `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options)` can be directly used for 2nd argument of for `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`. So I commented `Could you please confirm the value of "response" again?`. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to send the response from the first fetch to the second fetch. The response is a JSON object that looks like this: `{"title":"lecture1","Category":"cat5","shiurUrl":"https://www.example.com/#/lectures?v=109634","Id":"109634","_id":"xxxx","_createdDate":"2020-05-01T12:22:17.998Z","_updatedDate":"2020-05-01T12:22:17.998Z"}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I'm not sure about the detail of the API you want to use from your question, for example, if you want to directly use `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options)` as the payload of `var emailResponse =`, how about putting `options.payload = response.getContentText();` after `var response = ` and modifying to `var emailResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(EMAIL_URL, options);`? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution. So if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: If above modification didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the official document of the detail information of API you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Trying to use stringifyed object in place of advanced parameters

**Explanation**

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params), `fetch()` method has two parameters:

1. URL to issue the request to (required)
2. Object with advanced configuration parameters (optional)

Thus, passing anything other than an instance of `Object` will fail:

1. [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) returns a **string**, therefore an invalid data type.
2. `fetch()` method returns an instance of [`HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response), which is also not valid.

**Solution**

As suggested by Tanaike, after the first, but before the second request change the `payload` parameter to the content of the response and then use the `options`, not the `response`:

```
options.payload = response.getContentText();
```

**Notes**

1. There is a `contentType` advanced parameter, use this to set the type, the rest will be handled by the service, you don't need to explicitly set the header.